# R - change names of slots in list

Tags: r, list, rename

is there any way to rename slot names in list by the values that are within each slot. For example, in a list like this:

```
x <- list(c("name1","name2"), c("name1","name3"), c("name4","name5"))
names(x) <- c("a","b","c")
x
$a
[1] "name1" "name2"

$b
[1] "name1" "name3"

$c
[1] "name4" "name5"
```

I would like to change slot names in order to achieve something like this:

```
$name1;name2
[1] "name1" "name2"

$name1;name3
[1] "name1" "name3"

$name4;name5
[1] "name4" "name5"
```

Note: each slot can be variable in number.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that the resulting names are not valid syntax. This is just a bad idea and not useful at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
names(x) <- sapply(x,paste,collapse=";")
```

for each element of x, this pastes the string together, and then combines them into a vector. This can be used to set `names(x)` as you showed.

Comment: @PedroA Note that you need to use quotes to access to an element of the list e.g : `x$"name1;name2"`. Or you have to change the separator in your name. Because in R ";" is used to separate operations : `x$name1;name2` will return the element "name1" in the list "x" and the objet "name2" of the current environement.